# How to get Content Editable div width while writing text inside it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project of HTML and javascript. I have follwing code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .mainDiv
    {
        border:1px solid black;
        width:500px;
        height:340px;
        left:400px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .textOutsideDiv
    {
        border: 1px dashed black;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width:20px;
        height: 20px; 
    }
    .textInsideDiv {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border: medium none;
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
        line-height: 1em;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 1em;
        min-width: 1px;
        outline: medium none;
        padding: 2px;
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeTextCanvas(e)
    {
        var mouseX=e.pageX-401;
        var mouseY=e.pageY-9;
        var existOrNot=document.getElementById('textOutsideDiv').style.display;

        if(existOrNot=="" || existOrNot=="none")
        {   
            var outerContainer=document.getElementById('textOutsideDiv');
            var innerContainer=document.getElementById('textInsideDiv');

            outerContainer.style.display='block';
            outerContainer.style.left=mouseX+'px';
            outerContainer.style.top=mouseY+'px';

            innerContainer.style.display='block';
        }

    }
    function makeDiv()
    {
        //alert("Write Inside");
            var outerContainer=document.getElementById('textOutsideDiv');
            var innerContainer=document.getElementById('textInsideDiv');

            var h=innerContainer.offsetHeight;
            outerContainer.style.height=h+'px';

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv" onclick="makeTextCanvas(event);">
    <div id="textOutsideDiv" class="textOutsideDiv">
        <div id="textInsideDiv" class="textInsideDiv" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="makeDiv();" style="font-size: 1em; color: rgb(0, 170, 0);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On changing content inside div, i am increasing outerContainer div's height but i am facing a problem in getting width of Content Editable div. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you say that you want to get width of the inner `div`, but actually you are trying to get `innerContainer.offsetHeight`. Second, adding text to an element that has its width set to auto does not stretch it if its parent element has fixed width.

If I understood correctly what you were trying to achieve, you want to expand your pseudo-textbox while the user is typing. Here is how you can expand it: http://jsfiddle.net/LwCWM/1/ , but there should be a better way of getting width of the text since non-monospace fonts have letters of various widths.

Comment: Thank for action. But how can i make this kind of div free from spelling check. Because spellCheck=='false' is not working on the contenteditable='true' div.